# Framework 7 vue, validate on success

Tags: javascript, vue.js, html-framework-7

Using framework 7 vue (current version 4.4.3), I'm trying to validate a form on submit. I have found the following code:   http://forum.framework7.io/t/solved-how-to-validate-form-using-button-v2/1889

```
  $$('.save').on('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  if (!$$('#form-name')[0].checkValidity()) {

    console.log('Check Validity!');

  } else {

    //ajax request here
    return false;

  }
```

});

However, I am having difficulty trying to translate this to work in vue. Logging out the form object, I cant see a checkValidity option...

I have been able to access the form data through

```
 const formData = this.$f7.form.convertToData('#ajaxForm')
```

I am using framework7's inputs

```
<f7-list >
  <f7-list-input v-for="field in form"
    :name="field.name"
    :value="field.value"
    @input="field.value = $event.target.value"
    :label="field.label"
    :type="field.type"
    :placeholder="field.placeholder"
    :info="field.info"
    :required="field.required"
    :validate="field.validate"
    clear-button
  >
  </f7-list-input>
</f7-list>
```

validation also works via the props... Just cant fathom out how to trigger it on submit. I'm assuming I need access to framework 7's dom as per the example? - I tried to access Dom7 - but this is undefined... I guess because vue is being used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So.... Dom7 is available as this.Dom7.... the checkValidity method is available on that. Feels a bit like jQuery :)

```
 const $$ = this.Dom7

      if (!$$('#ajaxForm')[0].checkValidity()) {

        console.log('Check Validity!');

      } else {

        //ajax request here
        return false;

      }
```